# Only css or css3 slider

Tags: html, css

Hello to everyone i need multiple slider only with css/html
i should not use javascript or jquery, please can someone help me?

I should show 3 images, and than onlcikc on the arrows it should show another pictures(like in the image)
[image]

```css
.partnersImg{
    width: 100%;
}
.nextIcon, .prevIcon{
width: 50px;
}
```

```html
            <div class="patertnerSlider">
              <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcStFrWoQm1J07yYet23ECYxiKd55MWRbU9r19h64ROUOaeQ9FQB" class="prevIcon">
              <br>
              <img src="https://image.freepik.com/iconen-gratis/naar-de-volgende-pagina-symbool_318-35629.jpg" class="nextIcon">
              <div class="mainSlider">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoLohLLjZL3np_ey31ECbmOg7ayJsvZTz92JUo0TPlL4ADfUzQ" class="partnersImg">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoLohLLjZL3np_ey31ECbmOg7ayJsvZTz92JUo0TPlL4ADfUzQ" class="partnersImg">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoLohLLjZL3np_ey31ECbmOg7ayJsvZTz92JUo0TPlL4ADfUzQ" class="partnersImg">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoLohLLjZL3np_ey31ECbmOg7ayJsvZTz92JUo0TPlL4ADfUzQ" class="partnersImg">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoLohLLjZL3np_ey31ECbmOg7ayJsvZTz92JUo0TPlL4ADfUzQ" class="partnersImg">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoLohLLjZL3np_ey31ECbmOg7ayJsvZTz92JUo0TPlL4ADfUzQ" class="partnersImg">
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: how can you handle the click events of advancing the next slide without javascript?

Comment: @zgood  there is some methods, but i could not find it, with css3 it is really possible

Comment: CSS is for styling, not scripting events and logic. If you can find a css3 property that lets you attach and handle an event I would like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can get some inspiration from [this article from 2015](https://corpocrat.com/2015/12/09/20-cool-pure-css-sliders-without-jqueryjavascript/).

I didn't look at all of them but the two I did look at suggested:

- If you only want the 'clicks' to navigate the slider, you can use a 'tab-like' functionality which relies on clicking internal links (`href=#something`) which modifies the url and shows the correct 'tab' by showing the element with the corresponding ID (http://benschwarz.github.io/gallery-css/)
- If you want it to auto-transition you can use keyframes like [this example's Demo 1](https://github.com/stephenscaff/keyframes-slider).

The code below is from the source code of option 2, please visit site to see the rest, too much to put in an answer! It's a combination of animations an keyframes fading into each other.

```
background-image: url(../images/banner-1-sm.jpg);
animation: slider-sm ease-in-out 30s both infinite;

...

animation: fade-out 9s infinite both;
background-image: url(../images/banner-2-sm.jpg);

...

@keyframes fade-out {
  33% {
    opacity: 1; }
  66% {
    opacity: 0; } }

...

@keyframes slider-sm {
  0% {
    background-image: url(../images/banner-1-sm.jpg); }
  33% {
    background-image: url(../images/banner-2-sm.jpg); }
  66% {
    background-image: url(../images/banner-3-sm.jpg); }
  100% {
    background-image: url(../images/banner-1-sm.jpg); } }
```

@zgood I wondered the same thing (if it was possible with pure CSS). It seems like there are limitations, but amazingly, you can!

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. In addition, this question is asking for software to be written which makes his question off topic and it will be deleted eventually. Please do not answer off topic questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer